# Filter dropdown with subcategories in angular

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, angularjs

I have two dropdowns that I populate with data from the server. The first dropdown contains a category, and the second one contains all the subcategories. Like so:

```
<select ng-model="category1">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="category1">
    <option value="4">Subitem 1</option>
    <option value="5">Subitem 2</option>
</select>
```

Subcategories are linked to main categories by a property "parentID", so in the example above, Subitem 1 could have a parentID = 2, which means Subitem1 has the maincategory of Item 2.

I want the users to be able to select a main category OR a subcategory.

- Selecting a main category should filter the second dropdown to only show the subcategories linked to that category (i.e. the subcategories with THAT parentID)
- Subcategories can only be selected if a main category has been selected

My question is, how do achieve this filtering in angular? I'm thinking I should use ng-options and angulars filters in some way, but I'm not sure how.

Right now the second dropdowns contains all subcategories regardless of the selected value in the first dropdown. I know I have to use my parentID in the filter to identify which subcategories that should be visible, but where do I put it?

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: I answered a similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178243/bind-ng-options-to-remote-json-data/16178553#16178553

Answer (score 2):

I am still a bit new with AngularJS, so this might not be the best or the most elegant solution, but works for me:

OK, I solved this in a following way:

1) Populated the two select boxes over an ng-repeat command:

```
<select ng-model="categoryId" ng-change="updateSubcategorySelect()">
  <option ng-repeat="category in categoryList" value="{{category.Id}}">
    {{category.Name}}
  </option>
</select>
<select ng-model="subcategoryId">
  <option ng-repeat="subcategory in subcategoryList" value="{{subcategory.Id}}">
    {{subcategory.Name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

where the function updateSubcategorySelect is defined in the AngularJS controller and looks like this:

```
$scope.updateSubcategorySelect= function () {
    $scope.subcategoryList= Subcategory.query({
        categoryId: $scope.categoryId
    });
}
```

(of course, this assumes you are popuating your list using an API where the factory Subcategory is defined and has a get method that takes categoryId as a parameter, but you can populate / filter your list any other way!)

So, the idea is to call a function on change of the categoryList to reevaluate the data behind the subcategoryList.

I have not worked on disabling the subCategory list if a category is not selected, but it should be something like this (in the definition of the second select box):

```
  <select ng-model="subcategoryId" ng-disabled="countryId === 0 || countryId === undefined">
```

However, ng-disabled doesn't seem to work well with select boxes, so you might need something like this here:
[ng:disabled does not work with select html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288436/ngdisabled-does-not-work-with-select-html-element)

Hope this helps.