# AnglularJS: Populate second select-dropdown based on choice of first select-dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a set of select-dropdown menus, I am trying to populate second select-dropdown based on choice of first select-dropdown in angularJS. I don't know how to actually start with this.

I have all model ready but am struggling with the dynamic population.

**Select 1:**

```
    <select ng-model="selectedSource" ng-options="source.name for source in sourceList">
       <option value="">-- Select item --</option>
    </select>

$scope.sourceList= [
    {
       "name":"Person",
       "has": ["a","b","c"]
    },
    {
       "name":"Car",
       "has": ["1","2","3"]
    }
];
```

**What am trying to achieve:**

When `sourceList.name` is `Person` populate 2nd select-dropdown with `targerSet1`

```
$scope.targerSet1= [
   {
      "name":"King Julien"
   }
];
```

When `sourceList.name` is `Car` populate 2nd select-dropdown with `targerSet2`

```
$scope.targerSet2= [
   {
      "name":"RoyalMobile"
   }
];
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191060/filter-dropdown-with-subcategories-in-angular).

Comment: I am aware it might be a duplicate.. but that one didn't really help.

Comment: One controller, two models is the way to go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345020/populate-dropdown-2-based-on-dropdown-1-selection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use binded variable from first select in `ng-options` of second one:

**Selects**

```
<select ng-model="selectedSource" ng-options="source.name for source in sourceList">
    <option value="">-- Select item --</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in selectedSource.suboptions">
    <option value="">-- Select item --</option>
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.sourceList = [
    {
       name: "Person",
       suboptions: [
           { name: "King Julien" }
       ]
    },
    {
       name: "Car",
       suboptions: [
           { name: "RoyalMobile" }
       ]
    }
];
```